# python string replace is deleting whitespace incorrectly

Tags: python, string, replace, whitespace

I have a method

```
def strip_searchname(self, original_name):
    taboo = {" and ", " of ", " at ", " in ", ":", "-", ",", " the ", " "}
    searchname = original_name
    for word in taboo:
        print(searchname)
        searchname = searchname.replace(word, "")
    searchname = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', "", searchname)
    searchname= searchname.upper()
    return searchname
```

(yes, I know parts of it are redundant)

The first .replace seems to be stripping the entire string of whitespace, which I do NOT want. Why is this? How do I avoid it?

(e.g. output is:

```
Seattle University
SeattleUniversity
SeattleUniversity
SeattleUniversity
SeattleUniversity
SeattleUniversity
SeattleUniversity
SeattleUniversity
SeattleUniversity
SEATTLEUNIVERSITY
```

)

Comment: The " " replacement at the end of `taboo` will clearly replace all whitespace.  What's your question?

Comment: Yes, but it is the last replacement. As you can see from the example output, it's deleting *all* of the spaces the first time through-- i.e. on " and "

Comment: "As you can see from the example output"  Sorry.  Can't see that.  Can you provide a more clear example that proves that the `" and "` (and only that) is broken?  Perhaps a subset of your code?

Comment: I reformatted the output so that it is easier to read. walking through the loop, I would think that it would stay "Seattle University" until the 2nd to last line, when the " " replace comes in.

Comment: I still don't see any evidence that the `" and "` is what removed all the whitespace.  Please provide a really clear proof that even a dummy can follow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What I DON'T understand is why it seems to be executing the " "
>   replace BEFORE the " of " replace, for example, when the " of "
>   replace comes before the space in the list.

It's not a list.

```
taboo = {" and ", " of ", " at ", " in ", ":", "-", ",", " the ", " "}
```

is a set literal.  Try replacing { and } by [ and ] to get the order you want.

Comment: There it is. Thank you! (I'm still getting used to Python syntax)

Answer (score 0):

the replace method on a string replaces all occurences of the first argument with the second argument.  In your loop, when the string `word` equals `" "`, the replace method will delete all occurrences of `" "` in `searchname`.

Comment: I understand that. What I DON'T understand is why it seems to be executing the " " replace BEFORE the " of " replace, for example, when the " of " replace comes before the space in the list.

Comment: perhaps the loop is not being performed in the order you'd expect.  try printing `word` as well as `searchname` in your debug statement?

Comment: That happens because you're looping a set. If the order of taboo strings that must be removed matters to you, you shouldn't use a set but something like a list or a tuple, i.e. a data type in which order is taken in account.

Comment: already answerd i see, replacing `set`  with `list` should do the trick `[" and ", " of ", ....]`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that `taboo` is not a list, it is a set and sets do not keep the order.

See

```
>>> taboo = ['a', 'b', ' ']
>>> print taboo
['a', 'b', ' ']
>>> taboo = {'a', 'b', ' '}
>>> print taboo
set(['a', ' ', 'b'])
```

Comment: That's a set, not a dict. (ed: amended)